# javascript object append sub children

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, object, append

did not manage to find a similar issue in the forum so I hoped you could help with that.

I've got a multi layer object that I would like to append as different lists as HTML using javascript.

Here is how the obj is built:

```
var obj = [
  {
    month: "A",
    content: [
      {
        name: "A-content",
        image: "A-image"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    month: "B",
    content: [
      {
        name: "B-content",
        image: "B-image"
      }
   ]
  }
];
```

And here is how I am looping:

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
 var contents = obj[i].content;

 // Create list
 var blogList = '<ul class="blog-list"></ul>';

 // Append list
 $('body').append(blogList);

  for(var j = 0; j < contents.length; j++) {
   var blogName = contents[j].name,
       blogImage = contents[j].image;

   // How to append these sub element to corresponding parent ???
      $('.blog-list').append('<li>'+ blogName + blogImage +'</li>')
 }
}
```

On second loop, children appears but not in corresponding parents. (ex: I have the children from B going into the A list);

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line...

```
$('.blog-list')
```

... selects **all** the elements with class `blog-list` from live DOM, and not just the one just created. One possible way around this problem is storing the jQuery-wrapped (`<ul>`) element, then reusing it when appending `<li>`-s:

```
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  var contents = obj[i].content;

  // Create list
  var $blogList = $('<ul class="blog-list"></ul>');
  for(var j = 0; j < contents.length; j++) {
     var blogName = contents[j].name,
         blogImage = contents[j].image;

     // reusing the $blogList element
     $blogList.append('<li>'+ blogName + blogImage +'</li>');
  }

  // Append list
  $('body').append($blogList);
}
```

Notice that I moved appending that element to `body` further down the loop. It won't matter in this particular snippet, but usually it's better to postpone appending to 'live' DOM as far as possible.

You can extend this idea by using array of bloglists instead:

```
var bloglists = obj.map(function(contents) {
  var $bloglist = $('<ul class="blog-list"></ul>');
  contents.forEach(function(blogData) {
    var $li = $('<li></li>');
    $li.text(blogData.name + blogData.image);
    $bloglist.append($li); 
  });
  return $bloglist[0];
});

$('body').append(bloglists);
```

Not only this code updates live DOM only when it's fully prepared, it also eliminates XSS threat coming from rogue `blogName` and `blogImage` values. If that's not necessary, just reuse the technique given in the first snippet.